# $L^p$ convergence of composition

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^{p}(U)$ and $(t_{n})$ be a sequence of functions from $U$ to $U$ such that $$t_{n} \rightarrow \operatorname{id},$$
in the space $L^{\infty}(U)$.

Does the following hold:
$$f \circ t_{n} \rightarrow f,$$
in the space $L^{p}(U)$?

I tried using the dominated convergence theorem for $p_{n}(x)=\left|f(x) - f(t_{n}(x))\right|^{p}$ to show that the statement is true, but I couldn't find the "dominating" function.

Comment: Maybe another convergence theorem is more appropriate. Have you tried applying the Vitali convergence theorem? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem

Comment: please add some context, is $p>1$? $is U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$? is the measure the Lebesgue measure? are $t_n$ continuous? In your attempt there is not even pointwise convergence.

Comment: Yes, Lebesgue measure is used and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, but $p$ is not restricted (in order to see when the statement holds and when it does not).
Doesn't the uniform convergence imply pointwise convergence, for almost all points?

Thank you for the "Vitali convergence", I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes, but you cant know that if $x_n\to x$ then $ f(x_n)\to f(x)$ if $f$ is not continuous

Comment: Is $U$ of finite measure?

Comment: Maybe the missing continuity of $f$ can be overcome by Lusin's theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem) and using convergence in measure instead of pointwise convergence (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure). For this to work $U$ will probably need to be bounded.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn, of course, you're right...
$U$ is not presumed to be bounded.

Comment: @humanStampedist, thank you for the idea, I'll see what I can do...

Answer (score 1):

For the convergence to happen, it is important to know how $t_n$ mixes the domain $U$. And there is a subtle technical issue associated with the definition of $L^p$. Let $U=[0,1]$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure and $t_n$ be
$$
t_n(x) = \frac{k}{2^n}
$$ for $x\in [\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n})$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,2^n$. We can easily see that $t_n \to \operatorname{id}$ in $L^\infty$. An issue here is that
$$
f\mapsto  f\circ t_n
$$ is not well-defined on $L^p([0,1])$. To see this, recall that $L^p([0,1])$ space is not a family of functions, but a family of equivalence classes of functions. Pick $0 = 1_\mathbb{Q} $ in $L^p([0,1])$. The composition with $t_n$ gives incompatible results that
$$
1_\mathbb{Q}\circ t_n (x) = 1,
$$ while
$$
0\circ t_n(x) = 0. 
$$ Therefore, we see that composition may not be well-defined in general.

Instead of $L^p$ of equivalence classes, we may adopt the space 
$$
\mathcal{L}^p = \{f:U\to \mathbb{C}\;|\;f\text{ is measurable},\int_U|f|^p dx <\infty\}
$$ of actual functions. However, we can see that the convergence can also fail in this case by the example
$$
1_\mathbb{Q}\circ t_n = 1 \not\to 1_\mathbb{Q}.
$$ Thus, unfortunately, we conclude that mixing up the domain does not work properly in general. To properly define composition, some additional conditions such as preserving measure should be imposed on $t_n$.